# Loading a file not in the classpath into a Spring Resource?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I currently have a Spring API service that takes a Base64 String img and decodes it.

```
String imageDataBytes = img.substring(img.indexOf(",")+1);
InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(Base64.decodeBase64(imageDataBytes));
```

I want to load contents of stream onto a Resource class. But so far my research is telling me I can only load resources through a URL or file path, which I don't have here. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ByteArrayResource. It takes a byte array in constructor. Here is the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/ByteArrayResource.html) .